# Panorama control truncating long titles

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create a simple Windows Phone 7 app in which one of the pages uses a [Panorama control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941104%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). My control has five `PanoramaItem` children. Using the code below, the title is truncated on the fourth screen in the middle of the word "anyone." How can I make the Panorama control display the full title?

```
<controls:Panorama Title="This is the longest title anyone has ever seen" >
```

Comment: Shorten it (in other words you don't)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to be limited to be 1024px in width. (The same as the background image width.)

This constraint is perfectly fine within the intended use of the Panorama header/title. From the UI Design and Interaction Guide:

> It is meant to let the user identify the application

and

> Use the same panorama title for the launch tile in Start for consistency.

Due to space restrictions on the Start Tile and the application list a guideline of 13 characters is suggested to avoid text clipping. This will also definitely fit on a panorama header.

Comment: When using the Panorama view as the main application page, this makes perfect sense. However, I plan on using it as a sub-view of the main page.

Comment: Also, the title will be of variable length, so I can't promise that it will be <1024px wide.

Comment: @oltman the panorama was not designed to be used this way. A Panorama is intended as a primary navigation aid. If you really need to use it in ways beyond it ws intended you could consider making your own version which you customize to your specific needs.

Comment: Hmmm. In trying to hack around it, I nested the Panorama control in a Canvas alongside a TextBlock, which I animate on manipulation and selection changed. However, this TextBlock also seems to be getting truncated to 1024px wide. Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe panorama page title has to fit within 1000 px.

Comment: Good to know. Is this documented anywhere? Is there some way around this? It seems like a very silly constraint, and the page's title is dynamic, so I won't always be able to guarantee that it will be <100 px.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the number of panes you have.